# Arduino Simulink

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink, arduino-uno

I have this problem.

[image: schema]

How can I measure my own PWM signal again by analog inputs? I always get a signal = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a "scope" block to check signals are true or not. Also please check the conditions of the blocks.